# Promise.all & .map am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, nestjs

I'm using typescript and try to set some value to a property in object.

I have a array of objects like..

```
a = [{id:1, name:'a', image:'image.jpg'}, {id:2, name:'b', image:'image2.jpg'}]
```

and would like to do set some value to the property so that it becomes

```
a = [
     {id:1, name:'a', image:'image.jpg', imageObj:{some object}, isConfirmed: true}, 
     {id:2, name:'b', image:'image2.jpg',imageObj:{some object}, isConfirmed: false}
]
```

this is part of my code:

```
await Promise.all(
        a.map(async dto => {
          dto.isConfirmed = await this.postService.checkConfirmed(dto);
          if (!dto.image) return;
          dto.imageObj = this.service.createImageObj(dto);
        })
      );

return a;
```

`checkConfirmed` is async function that searches db.

```
if (!dto.image) return;
dto.imageObj = this.service.createImageObj(dto);
```

↑`createImageObj` does not involve any asynchronous job and I want to created Image obejct only when dto.image exist.

so my question is:
am I doing this right?
what I am worrying about is..
could there be a case where `isConfirmed` property is never assigned (returned as undefined) because `if (!dto.image) return;` is executed before `isConfirmed` is assigned?

Comment: `return await Promise.all(/* ... */)`. If you just do `return a;` that's the array you had *before*, not the one you've produced after asynchronously mapping over.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I've still got a = [ {id:1, name:'a', image:'image.jpg', imageObj:{some object}, isConfirmed: true},       {id:2, name:'b', image:'image2.jpg',imageObj:{some object}, isConfirmed: false} ] when I just `return a;` do you know why? ＠VLAZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `async await` inside either `forEach` or `map`.

```
const result = await Promise.all(
  a.map(dto => this.postService.checkConfirmed(dto));
);

a.forEach((dto, index) => {
  dto.isConfirmed = result[index]
  if (!dto.image) return;
  dto.imageObj = this.service.createImageObj(dto);
})

return a;
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot return in the map:

```
await Promise.all(
    a.map(async dto => {
      dto.isConfirmed = await this.postService.checkConfirmed(dto);
      if (!dto.image) return dto;
      dto.imageObj = this.service.createImageObj(dto);
      return dto;
    })
  );

return a;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. With my code above(without return inside map), I've still got `a = [
     {id:1, name:'a', image:'image.jpg', imageObj:{some object}, isConfirmed: true}, 
     {id:2, name:'b', image:'image2.jpg',imageObj:{some object}, isConfirmed: false}
]`  do you know why?

Comment: @amu03 what did you want to get?